# Python/MySQL error

Tags: python, mysql

I can't work out what the problem here is. The error code I keep getting is "Wrong number of arguments during string formatting" however I'm personally not seeing anything wrong with it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
def film_function(number, film):
    connection = connect(host='localhost', user='root', \
                                 passwd='', db='survey')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM persons, persons_films WHERE persons.person = persons_films.person AND number_of_films >= %s AND film = '%s' ORDER BY persons_films.person"

    cursor.execute(sql, [number], [film])
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if not rows:
        print ("No one in "+film+" found!")
    else:
        for row in rows:
            print row[0],"-", row[1]
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
cursor.execute(sql, [number], [film])
```

should be this:

```
cursor.execute(sql, [number, film])
```

You want to pass a single list of arguments, not individual lists each with a single argument.

Comment: Thanks for that. Not sure if you can help me with this but " print ("No one in "+film+" found!")" isn't working the way I want it to either. +film+ should have double quotes around it but the printed result only has single quotes even after I've attempted using single/double quotes together, triple quotes, etc. thoughts?

Comment: try `print ('No one in "'+film+'" found!')`